# Does the time of maximum of a diffusion process admit a continuous density?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $W$ be a standard one dimensional Brownian motion, and consider the solution $X$ to the SDE

$$dX_t = \mu(X_t) \, dt + \sigma(X_t) \, dW_t$$

with $X_0 = 0$ a.s., and where $\mu, \sigma: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ are Lipschitz continuous with $\sigma \geq c$ for some $c > 0$.

Fix $T > 0$, and denote $M_T := \max_{t \in [0, T]} X_t$.

I believe that by Girsanov’s theorem, followed by Dambins-Dubins-Schwartz, it is true that almost surely, there exists a unique random $\xi \in [0, T]$ such that $X_\xi = M_T$.

**Question:** Does the distribution of $\xi$ admit a continuous density with respect to Lebesgue measure?

Comment: see Nualart's work "Malliavin and related topics" Proposition 2.1.10.

Comment: and "Smoothness of the Distribution of the Supremum of a Multi-dimensional Diffusion Process" for more direct references.

Comment: @ThomasKojar I believe this gives the smoothness of the distribution of the maximum value, but the question asks for the distribution of the maximum time.

Comment: for the location, here is a reference for diffusions "On the joint distribution of the maximum and its location for a linear diffusion".

Comment: the xi has a nice relation with the max that you might be able to use in your setting: $\xi>r \Rightarrow M_{r}<M_{T}$ eg. see here "Time since maximum of Brownian motion and asymmetric Lévy processes".

Comment: Oh that’s indeed true! Thank you for the reference above too.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but is too long for a comment.

One can sample $\xi$ and plot the empirical distribution.  Taking the unit interval (i.e. $T=1$), we can plot the PDF and corresponding CDF.  I computed this by quantizing the unit interval into 1000 steps, and then sampled 100,000 instances of Brownian motion.

The plots below include the distributions for both $\max_t X_t$ and $\max_t |X_t|$.  Note that $\xi$ appears to be symmetric in $t$ around the midpoint; perhaps someone can see why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very interesting find…

Comment: That's the [third arcsine law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcsine_laws_(Wiener_process))

Comment: Whoa! Thank you, @MateuszKwaśnicki !